# bash script hangs sometimes

Tags: java, bash, scripting

I'm not getting what happens with this script: it should simply run the jar and the software for every file outputted from ls but at some files it stops and hangs in the jar part, the only thing I can do is kill it.
RE-starting the for loop from that file makes it work as well as running the jar directly on the file. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls ./src/RF/ | grep BEAM\.fa$)
do
    echo $file
    java -jar jar.jar > /dev/null
    ./otherscript
done
```

and I launch it with:

```
nohup ./bashscript.sh &
```

have I been clear?

Comment: Are there any files with spaces in their name?

Comment: nay, they are all of the form RF00###BEAM.fa. I'm pretty sure the ls|grep works well. It's something that happens later

Comment: I see in some lines you use `file.eps`. Do you mean `$file.eps` or is just a constant `file.eps`? Also, on `./otherscript -f file`. In general, quote your variables when using them --> `echo "$file"` and so on.

Comment: Ok, edited it. Sorry I misleaded your attention on quickly written part that were not important.
From htop I can clearly see it hangs on the jar file (while, as I said earlier, the jar runs with no problems on that file)

Comment: You could try removing the `> /dev/null` part and see the output. Or redirect it to a file and check the content. Also, does it work correctly if you run it directly with `./bashcript.sh` (no `nohup` neither background `&`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the problem was in the jar and appeared only in certain cases and quite randomly. Solved that, thanks for the inspiration!